# Retrieving text messages from stolen Android phone

Tags: 4.0-ice-cream-sandwich, sms, lost-phone

My Samsung Galaxy Nexus was stolen the other night. Is it possible to retrieve my texts and save them to my computer if I know the phone number and IMEI? I have a Gmail account set up on the phone but, haven't installed any backup app.

Answer (score 15):

Yes, its possible, from your desktop PC, go to Play Store, and install [AndroidLost](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.androidlost) remotely to your handset.

At this point, a ***caveat emptor*** is needed:

- *Provided you have 3G Data switched on, it will remotely install* on to the handset and also
- *There is sufficient battery power*

Read the starting page by visiting the main [AndroidLost](http://www.androidlost.com/#getstarted).

Send the text "***androidlost register***" (without the quotes) to your number of the handset that is stolen.

There's a box in the upper right hand corner of the [page](http://www.androidlost.com/#controls_Basic), Click on sign in, using your Google Account, if doing this for the first time, you will be prompted for AndroidLost to have permission to access your Google Account, as they are both tied into it together.

The message will appear - "Waiting for phone to be registered.", please be patient.

Wait for a while, sign out and sign back in, eventually, from there, you can remotely control the handset via that same website and fingers crossed it will have a happy ending.

Good luck :)

Comment: An additional point that ought to be noted: this won't work if the thief has wiped the phone or disconnected the owner's Google Account.

Answer (score 0):

NO, you cannot restore your text messages even if you know the phone number. If you didn't backup your phone with GMail, you can not get the backup because the text message are stored in phone's memory or SIM, not the SD. So, I think it is possible to get them back.

Comment: What's the relation between GMail and the phone memory or SIM?